# getting a error oledbexception was unhandled Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oledb

I am getting this error while trying to select data from a database and I am lost on how to fix it. My query works in my database but I am not sure what is happening

```
randomget = "SELECT top 1 id, Department, Team, Process,  SubProcess, SubTask, LastUpdatedBy from workload where stepstatus = 'complete' and agent is null or agent = 0  ";
OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection();
MyConn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=.......;Persist Security Info=False";;
MyConn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = MyConn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = randomget;
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
int id = 0;

while (reader.Read())
{
    id = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
    textBox8.Text = reader[6].ToString();
    textBox5.Text = reader[1].ToString();
    textBox6.Text = reader[2].ToString();
    textBox7.Text = reader[3].ToString();
    textBox9.Text = reader[4].ToString();
    textBox11.Text = reader[5].ToString();
    break;
} 

// input table name here 
textBox2.Text = agentsrf.ToString();
string sqlupdate = "Update workload set agent = '" + agent + "',  where ID = "  + id + " ' ";          
}

public OleDbConnection connection { get; set; }
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one stray `,` after `set agent = '" + agent + "'` just remove it and then it works fine. Also you should use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) because this kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
string sqlupdate = "Update workload set agent = @agent where ID = @id ";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agent", agent );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

Comment: I tried what you said but unfortunately  it does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. One of my field names had a space in it, which I did not spot.